# How to enable my internet filter (like k-9) to filter web pages accessed through Visual Studio 2012 web browser?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

I have an internet filter on my system which blocks inappropriate sites accessed through any of the common browsers including Internet Explorer. Any sites I access through VS however are not blocked. If anyone knows the name of the process used by VS 2012 for its web browser, I would be able to add that process to the filtering engine. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a reference for filtering engine in IE?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. My internet is filtered by an outside company called Nativ USA.

Comment: The Visual Studio web browser is embedded in the `devenv.exe` process.

Comment: Is there any way to target an embedded process- for example, to block an embedded process while still allowing parent process to run?

Comment: Guess you can out a filter on the port 80 and slows only some whitelist stuff to go through. But what is the real problem to resort to such measures?

Comment: Don't want full access to internet because of indecent content.

Comment: Strange, if your internet is filtered from outside then the internal browser to VS would also be already blocked as well. Can you confirm that you can access the block content from outside of VS insde the VS? If so then how is an outside company filtering your internet? by running an invasive program on your machine?

Comment: Every brower has an executable process which they manually filter on a browser by browser case. Since VS has only one process which the internal browser runs on, they can either block the entire VS or allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like [wireshark](http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/) to filter the packets.

Comment: What? Wireshark is a network protocol analyzer, not an internet filter. Sure it may be able to filter packets, but good luck setting it up as an proper internet filter.

Comment: @Brett , Yes what you say makes sense, I coundt find something else to suggest, but by the looks of what OP was asking, that is the closest thing I can think of. What I dont understand is why OP needs another filter if the filtering is already done externally? Does that make sense to you?